# Incremental aggregation in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I am beginner in informatica and while studying about incremental aggregation, I got stuck with this point:

**We cannot use incremental aggregation when the mapping includes an Aggregator transformation with Transaction transformation scope. The Workflow Manager marks the session invalid.**

I've searched a lot about it but did not get any answer. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the transformation - transaction control in your mapping you are telling integration service how the incoming records are grouped i.e. by a row, by transaction or by all input rows.

With transformation scope of "transaction" integration service honors the transaction boundaries. That means all the caches used during processing each transactions are reset once a new transaction is received.

To use incremental aggregator integration service must preserve the aggregator cache which is not possible when using transaction transformation scope.